# Increase/Decrease Line Indent shortcut

Tags: visual-studio, f#

Because Visual F# Tools cannot automatically indent code yet, I need to do the indents myself. Fortunately, I find that there are `Increase Line Indent` and `Decrease Line Indent` in the menu `Edit -> Advanced` of VS2017.

How can I put these shortcuts to the `Standard Toolbars`? I've looked at `Add or Remove Buttons -> Customize -> Add Command... -> Edit` but I couldn't find the buttons I need.

Comment: Have you tried selecting the lines and hitting `Tab` or `Shift+Tab`?

Comment: As whitespace conveys semantics (and not just syntax), tooling will never be able to completely auto-indent (only decrease indentation). Otherwise, whitespace would not need to be significant and the compiler could figure it out for himself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the commands are `Edit→Line Indent` and `Edit→Line Unindent` in the Commands dialogs.

Answer (score -1):

Select the block code or lines and press `Tab` to increase indent or `Shift+Tab` to decrease indent.